# Не поворачивается subview

Tags: ios

Не понятная ситуация. В настройках задана поддержка всех ориентаций.
Кручу главный экран, все поворачивается правильно.
Если из главного экрана вызвать subview в портретной ориентации. Subview вызывается в также в портретной ориентации и его можно вращать.
Если вызвать  из главного экрана subview в альбомной ориентации, то subview вызывается все равно в портретной ориетации???

Правильно работает только вот такой код
[code=cpp]
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations // iOS 6 autorotation fix
{
    NSLog(@"supportedInterfaceOrientations");

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width)];
}
else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.height, self.view.bounds.size.width)];
}

return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
```

}

[/code]

Answer (score 1):

любой элемент `view` отображается одинаково при любой ориентации экрана. Если хотите, чтобы отображение было разным, переопределите метод [`layoutSubviews`](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/layoutSubviews) - меняйте размеры и расположение фреймов в зависимости от положения экрана